# How to set receiver when any application launched in android.?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, event-receiver

i want to set receiver when ever any application get launched in android,after that i have to do some task.is there any way to do?

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

I have to set this receiver,when ever any application launched....

Comment: You can check it in launcher Activity for your application

Comment: Could you please post you code to achieve this whatever you have done,So that we can give you proper suggestion...

Comment: as like abve  i want to set receiver for any application opened.i have serched a lot but not getting

Comment: Please add the posted xml as edit of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to receive a broadcast whenever any application is launched. Unfortunately, there's no intent that is fired by the system for this, so it's not possible to receive a broadcast when any other application is launched. Though, you can determine the currently running application using ActivityManager and ComponentInfo (Google it, though this method will only work for pre-L devices, as Android L has removed this in view of increasing security). Hope this helps.

Comment: We appreciate your answer but doing in such way we have to do pooling in order to find the active activity all the time, which drains the battery. Usage Access can't check the active Activity?